# Returning multiple rows from an Ajax Call using JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to retrieve multiple rows back from an ajax call that I am making to a PHP file that connects to my MySql database.

My code looks as follows:

**JQuery/HTML**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function getComments(){
var boxid = document.location.hash.substring(1); // remove #    
    $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
             type: "POST",
             url: "getComments.php", //file name
             data: {boxid: boxid},
             success: function(server_response){        
                var data = $.parseJSON(server_response);
                var html = '', comment;
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    comment = data[i];
                    html += '<div id="' + comment.user_id + '"><span>' + comment.username + '</span><span>' + comment.comment + '</span></div>';
                }
                $('#ajax_comment').html(html);

             }
         });
}

});
</script>
<span name="ajax_comment" id="ajax_comment"></span>
```

**PHP (getComments.php)**

```
session_start();
include('config.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
else
$userid = 0;

if (isset($_POST['boxid']))
{
$knownid = $_POST['boxid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT u.id, u.USERNAME, c.COMMENT, c.DATE_ADDED, c.ACTIVE, c.id FROM ratemybox.USERS u, ratemybox.COMMENTS c WHERE u.id = c.user_id and c.box_id = $knownid ORDER BY c.DATE_ADDED DESC");

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$results = array();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $user_id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $dateAdded = $row['date_added'];

    $results[] = array("user_id" => $user_id, "username" => $username, "comment" => $comment, "date_added" => $dateAdded);
}

echo json_encode($results);
}
```

This is not producting the outcome I expect. Any advice would be great.

**EDIT**

When using Firebug I am getting the following errors:

```
Illegal string offset 'id' in 
Illegal string offset 'username'
Illegal string offset 'comment'
Illegal string offset 'date_added'
```

Not sure if this helps at all?

Comment: You say the code is not producing the outcome you expect, but what is the output you expect? And what is the current output?

Comment: At the very least can you wrap your `$knownid = $_POST['boxid']` in an `intval`? `$knownid = intval($_POST['boxid'])`. This isn't the preferred mechanism for SQL injection but anything will help in this code.

Comment: IT is not producing any output. I would expect a new div tag for every row that is returned with the correct information inside. This is produced in the Javascript function getComments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select query, you are trying to filter by the $knownid, however, you kept the variable within the quotes. Try changing to:

```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT u.id, u.USERNAME, c.COMMENT, c.DATE_ADDED, c.ACTIVE, c.id FROM ratemybox.USERS u, ratemybox.COMMENTS c WHERE u.id = c.user_id and c.box_id = " . $knownid . " ORDER BY c.DATE_ADDED DESC");
```

Comment: Text in double quotes is interpolated. The string would have been escaped as expected. Albeit subject to large SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the many suggestions already given (you really need to escape that $_POST["boxid"] before u add it to the query) its hard to find the problem with the code without some errors.

Try adding a var_dump($result) before the foreach to make sure your query is returning something or check the console of the browser to see what is actually being returned by the server.